# I have deleted a database and trying to create one with same name but get already exists error

Tags: azure-sql-database, azureportal

I have deleted a database in azure sql server via Azure Portal. Now I am trying to create a database in the same name by copying from an existing database. But I keep getting an error saying a database with the same name exists. But in the database listing, it is not there. I can see my earlier database in the deleted databases list. Any idea how to solve this issue as I need to create the new database in the same name.

[image]

Comment: try clearing browser cache and in  in-cognito mode.

Comment: *How* are you "copying" this database. There's no `COPY` command in T-SQL, so what steps are you doing to achieve this "copying"?

Comment: Also [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @ThomA I am copying through the Azure portal (https://portal.azure.com/ )

Comment: @everyone please do not under-rate questions. We are asking the questions in this platform because we actually facing practical issues and not just asking for fun. It is discouraging

Comment: How did you test whether the database exists?

Comment: @LajosArpad I queried using "Azure Data Studio", using below code and the db is not there in the result set.
SELECT name, database_id, create_date  
FROM sys.databases;

Comment: I see. Then it sounds like your database being cached. Are you sure you are connecting to the same database in both instances? If so, then it really really sounds like a caching problem.

Comment: @LajosArpad it sounds like the Azure Portal didn't get the updated state from the Azure database. Now it has been 2 days and still, the issue was there. I have sorted it out according to the answer provided below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are creating the database as a copy of an existing database, create the database with a different name instead of using the old database name. Once you do that  change the compute size and service tier of the newly created database to be the same as the old deleted database. After that you can change the name of the newly created database as the name of the deleted database using Transact-SQL ALTER DATABASE.

```
ALTER DATABASE [ORIGINAL-NAME] MODIFY NAME = [RENAMED-NAME]
```

Comment: Initially it looked as if it was a page caching issue. But I refreshed the page (Ctrl+Shift+R) but it didn't change. I have been getting the same result from Azure Portal after two days. So what I did was, I used another name to get it copied, then renamed the database to the intended name through the Azure Data Studio, like you mentioned. That worked! For some strange reason, the Azure portal held the old name and mentioned what's on the error image. Looks like the state did not get updated in the portal that the db is already deleted in sql server. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: It is a tricky process. You are welcome!

Comment: I had the same problem. This worked for me. Thanks.